# UIImagePickerController to import Image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

i want import image in ios  from library but i have error

> value of type 'viewcontroller' has no member 'present'

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @IBAction func Alert(sender: AnyObject) {

        let nextController = UIImagePickerController()
        self.present(nextController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my *stripped* working code. I use two pickers - one for camera, one for library - because of some odd iOS bug with tint color. To avoid "massive view controller" issues, I tend to move everything possible related to a a `UIImagePickerController` into a separate file and extension.

```
class OpenViewController: UIViewController {

    let pickerLibrary = UIImagePickerController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerLibrary.delegate = self

    }
}

extension OpenViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

   @objc func showImagePicker() {
        pickerLibrary.allowsEditing = false
        pickerLibrary.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(pickerLibrary,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
        pickerLibrary.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

While the `present` code looks correct, I notice several things you didn't post in your code. Maybe because you just didn't post it, but I would definitely check these things:

- Are you setting `ViewController` to be a delegate?
- Are you setting `ViewController.view` to be the source view? This may not be needed for iPhone, but definite helps with iPad.
- Have you includes everything needed to be working for `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate`?

Now as your error suggests, something else is likely the issue - a `UIViewController` **can** `present` another view controller. In this case you've given us no way to duplicate that error. In other words, I'm assuming that (1) You are seeing a `UIButton` attached to `Alert()` - BTW, Swift conventions use lower case for that - and (2) You've proven that when that button is tapped, `Alert() is actually executed.